# EF ObservableListSource Specify ForeignKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have two entities: `Employee` & `Contract`.

In the `Contract` entity I have the properties `AddedByEmployee` & `AssignedToEmployee`.

I want a collection navigation property in my `Employee` class but how do I reference the correct key in the `Contract` class?

So far I have:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    private readonly ObservableListSource<Contract> _Contracts = new ObservableListSource<Contract>();
    public virtual ObservableListSource<Contract> Contracts { get { return _Contracts; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public int ContractID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int AddedByEmployeeID {get; set;}
    public int AssignedToEmployeeID {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("AddedByEmployeeID")]
    public virtual Employee AddedByEmployee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignedToEmployeeID")]
    public virtual Employee AssignedToEmployee { get; set; }
}
```

So basically: How do I let the `ObservableListSource<Contract>` know it is the `AddedByEmployeeID` I want to map to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by either using `DataAnnotations` or the Fluent API.

Doing it with `DataAnnotations` you can add the `InverseProperty` attribute to either your `Contracts` or `AddedByEmployee` property (or both, but that is not necessary).

This will tell `Entity Framework` that a relationship should be made between `Contracts` and `AddedByEmployee`.

```
[InverseProperty("AddedByEmployee")]
public virtual List<Contract> Contracts
{
    get { return _Contracts; }
}
```

If you want to use the Fluent API instead, you simply have to explicitly define the relationship like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Contracts)
    .WithRequired(p => p.AddedByEmployee)
```